# How to know the type of a expression in runtime of a C++ program?

Tags: c++

Below is a program:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin>>t;
    if( std::strcmp( typeid((-1+sqrt(1+8*t))/2).name(), "i" ) == 0 )
        std::cout<<"YES";
    else
        std::cout<<"NO";
    return 0;
}
```

here `typeid((-1+sqrt(1+8*t))/2).name(),` evaluates at compile time(told by a teacher) and thus this is always going to return f(for float) or d(for decimal).

I want to know a way or any function which can tell me type of the expression at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense the type of the expression will never change as there is no polymorphism.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The type of that expression is set at compile time. The only dynamic typing available in C++ is via inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you expected that if the calculation returns a whole number (i.e. t == 1), the type changes? That's not how C++ works. It'll still be a `float`, but the value will be `1.f`.

Comment: @TBBle , TartanLlama yes, I want the same thing. can this be done by evaluating the expression and storing it into a float type variable and then checking the number after the decimal (.) if it is 0 then we can consider it as a integer?

Comment: @AryanKhan You should simply convert the float to an int and back. Then compare the result to your original float. When it is the same, the number is an integer: `if( static_cast<float>(static_cast<int>(myFloat)) == myFloat ) std::cout << "this has an integer value" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 3):

`typeid` only tells you about the *static* type determined at compile-time. The expression you're writing is always floating-point because of `sqrt`.  `typeid(int((-1+sqrt(1+8*t))/2)).name()`, on the other hand, would of course be `"i"`.

But I suppose that what you *actually* want is to know whether the operation has an integer result depending on the input.  The best you can do is to check if the calculated value (always floating-point value!) is close enough to an integer value, e.g.:

```
double val = (-1+sqrt(1+8*t))/2;
if (fabs(round(val) - val) < 1e-5) std::cout << "YES"; // and so on
```

Note that you can never expect the value to be *exactly* integral, because of floating-point imprecisions.  Hence I'm checking (in this example) that the difference between the rounded and original value is smaller than `1e-5`.

Also, I recommend to use `#include <cmath>` over `math.h`, and to use the functions from the `std` namespace (`std::round`, and so on).